# Long Vector Not Supported Yet Error in R Windows 64bit version

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, operating-system, size

I'm trying to test what the memory limitations in the current R version is.

```
runtest <- function(size) {
  x <- "testme"
  while(0<1) {
    x <- c(x, x)
    size <<- object.size(x)  # size of x when fail
  }
}
```

By running `runtest(size)` in the console on my laptop, I get the following error:

```
> runtest(size)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 7915Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 7915Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 7915Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 7915Mb: see help(memory.size)
> size
2147483736 bytes
>
```

This size looks very close to the 2^31-1 limit that people have mentioned before. So then I tried running the same code on our upgraded desktop with 128GB of RAM and set the variable in the shortcut for the 64 bit version to the max memory usage of 100GB. This is the new error I get:

```
Error in structure(.Call(C_objectSize, ), class = "object_size"):
  long vectors not supported yet: unique.c: 1720
> size
8589934680 bytes
>
```

Does this 8.5GB limit have anything to do with running in Windows O/S (specifically Windows 7 Enterprise edition)? I think the R help file (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) explains this, but I'm having trouble understanding what it's saying (not my area of expertise).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the definition of "long vector" is but this is almost certainly a limitation of datatype, not system memory.

Comment: I agree that the linked Memory-limits.html page is confusing, if you're looking for limits on the 64-bit build.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have, some have artificial limits imposed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Both laptop and spare desktop are running Windows 7 Enterprise edition 64-bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source of [size.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/src/size.c) and [unique.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/unique.c) it looks like the hashing used to improve `object.size` doesn't support long vectors yet:

```
/* Use hashing to improve object.size. Here we want equal CHARSXPs,
   not equal contents. */
```

and

```
/*  Currently the hash table is implemented as a (signed) integer
    array.  So there are two 31-bit restrictions, the length of the
    array and the values.  The values are initially NIL (-1).  O-based
    indices are inserted by isDuplicated, and invalidated by setting
    to NA_INTEGER.
*/
```

Therefore, it is `object.size` that is choking. How about calling `numeric(2^36)` to see if you can create a such a large object, (should be 64GB).

Answer (score 3):

The maximum vector length in recent versions of R is 2^53-1 because there are 53 bits in the mantissa of the double storage mode. The maximum extent of each dimension of a matrix or array is still 2^32-1 because dimension values are still based on the integer storage mode. I thought I might get more information from `news()` but didn't get as much as I thought I would. There was quite a bit of discussion about this on the r-devel mailing list and I would use Advanced Search: https://www.google.com/advanced_search of the r-devel mailing list by putting `https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel` in the "site" slot if I needed more.

```
?double
?integer

db <- news()
str(db)
db$Text[grepl("vector", db$Text) & grepl("length", db$Text)]
# only slsightly informative
db$Text[grepl("vector", db$Text) & grepl("long", db$Text)][3]
```

> [1] "There is support for vectors longer than 2^31 - 1 elements.  This\napplies to raw, logical, integer, double, complex and character\nvectors, as well as lists.  (Elements of character vectors remain\nlimited to 2^31 - 1 bytes.)"