# Maximum number of objects in r workspace

Tags: r

Is there a limit on the number (not size) of objects an R workspace may contain? What is the maximum possible value of `length(e)`, where `e` is an environment?

(`length(e)` contains the number of variable in `e`; it is the same as `length(ls(e))`.)

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the size of the smallest object possible, and how much memory you have available to use?

Comment: In a 64-bit system I think it's 2^53-1. Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21142236/602276

Comment: I suspect it is no more than `.Machine$integer.max #[1] 2147483647` since indexing is done in integer mode, but wouldn't be surprised to find a lower limit imposed by implementation details.

Comment: I was writing an answer but I got to wondering. For assignments etc (i.e. `<-`) you supply an environment within which to assign the object. The number of objects in an `environment` must be limited by the `int` data type for the reason @BondedDust states, but I guess it is possible that each environment can hold `2147483647` objects essentially giving you a limitless number of objects limited only by your machine memory.

Comment: This is interesting to me. My intuition would be the same as @SimonO'Hanlon's: namely, that there might be a cap on the printing of `ls()` but that the only true upper limit is memory.

Comment: I edited this to simplify, since you don't need `ls` to count the number of variables.  But feel free to revert if you really did care about how many objects `ls` will print.

Comment: I have never heard of someone reaching such a limit.The reason people are advised to store objects in lists rather than in a profusion of separately named objects is not because of limits on the numbers of objects but rather because of the difficulties in access and management and possibilities of confusion when the numbers of names expands.

Answer (score 4):

The source code for `ls()` (in [**`src/main/envir.c`**](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/envir_8c_source.html#l02518)) defines it's return value using another function: `return R_lsInternal(env, all);`;

```
 #2518 SEXP attribute_hidden do_ls(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho)
 #2519 {
 #2520     SEXP env;
 #2521     int all;
 #....
 #2537     return R_lsInternal(env, all);
 #2538 }
```

The return function `return R_lsInternal(env, all);`, *takes a list of environments and a boolean indicating whether to get all names* and is defined at [**line 2452 of the `envir.c`**](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/envir_8c_source.html#l02542). It computes the length of names of objects in an environment(s) storing the length in an `int` datatype (`k` below), therefore the number of objects in an environment must be bounded by the maximum size of this datatype:

```
 #2542 SEXP R_lsInternal(SEXP env, Rboolean all)
 #2543 {
 #2544     int  k;    <==== INTEGER TYPE DEFINED HERE LIMITS NUMBER OF OBJECTS IN ENVIRONMENT
 #2545     SEXP ans;
 #2546 
 #2547 
 #2548     /* Step 1 : Compute the Vector Size */
 #2549     k = 0;
 #2550     if (env == R_BaseEnv || env == R_BaseNamespace)
 #2551     k += BuiltinSize(all, 0);
 #...
 #2562     /* Step 2 : Allocate and Fill the Result */
 #2563     PROTECT(ans = allocVector(STRSXP, k));
 #...
 #2576     return ans;
 #2577 }
```

However, this is for the objects in a specified `environment`. I see no reason that you can't specify sub-environements, each of which could have `.Machine$integer.max` objects in it! So the limit should only be bounded by your machine memory. I'd love someone to test this though!

```
#  Example of assigning values in sub environments...
e <- new.env()
e$f <- new.env()

# Environment `e` now has one object in, which is another environment...
length ( ls( e ) )
# [1] 1

e$f$a <- 2

# Environment `f` now also has one object in, which is `a`
length ( ls( e$f ) )
# [1] 1
```

Note: if you compute the length of objects using `length(e)` where `e` is an environment then the function `envlength` will be dispatched as `length` is an internal generic for which there are several methods written for various object types, including one for environments, as noted by @RichieCotton above and @hadley in the comments below.

Comment: `all` is a boolean (stored in an int) indicating whether or not to return all values - it's not the return value of `ls()`.

Comment: The relevant function is actually `envlength`, https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/24a4576064961a51154f096519f20177096edec1/src/main/envir.c#L2747

Comment: @hadley not according to the question as it was originally framed before the edit by Richie Cotton (`length(ls())`). And if you bothered to read the second half of my question you will realise I never make this claim about `all`. I specifically state that the return value `return R_lsInternal(env, all);` is still bounded by the maximum size of `int`. And although I don't state it, that is because the return vector `ans` of the `R_lsinternal` function (that I reference!) is instantiated thus: `PROTECT(ans = allocVector(STRSXP, k));` and `k` is an `int`.

Comment: I was responding to the first sentence, which says: "defines it's return value all as type int". Your answer is confusing because you have included code that isn't not that relevant, while leaving the important parts as references. `all` is a total red herring, and `envlength` is more important because it define the size of an environment, not the size of the vector returned by `ls()` (that's an admittedly subtle distinction).

Comment: @hadley I updated to alleviate any confusion. I do think it is a little unfair to base your comments to an entire answer based on the first sentence alone. And regardless of whether `envlength` is more important, I was answering for an entirely different posted question!

Comment: I think your answer now captures the essence of the problem accurately.